# Image not showing on the window

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

I have reduced my codes to such a simple function: to show a picture on a window. But why does the picture not show up however I tried? I create a JFrame, and then created a JPanel which is expected to show the picture. Then add the panel to the frame. By the way, I imported the picture and double clicked it to get the url.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.sun.prism.Graphics;

public class GUI {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("My game");
    JPanel gamePanel=new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUI gui=new GUI();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go(){

        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Background backPic=new Background();
        backPic.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(backPic);        

        JPanel contentPane=(JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setOpaque(false);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    class Background extends JPanel{
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                ImageIcon backgroundIcon=new         ImageIcon("file:///E:/eclipse/EL/backgroundPicture.jpg");
                Image backgroundPic=backgroundIcon.getImage();

                Graphics2D g2D=(Graphics2D) g;
                g2D.drawImage(backgroundPic,0,0,this);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've imported `com.sun.prism.Graphics`.  It should be `java.awt.Graphics`.

I would also get rid of the "file:///" bit from your path.  And you also probably don't want to be loading the image on each paint event.  Here's a better version of the Background class;-

```
class Background extends JPanel {

    Image backgroundPic;

    public Background() {
        ImageIcon backgroundIcon=new ImageIcon("E:/eclipse/EL/backgroundPicture.jpg");
        backgroundPic=backgroundIcon.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D=(Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.drawImage(backgroundPic,10,10,this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which means you are providing a new method ´paintComponent(com.sun.prism.Graphics)´ and NOT overriding paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics).

Comment: @DavidGilbert *"Which means you are providing a new method"* One reason why `@Override` should be specified on any overridden method. It's handy to get compiler warnings that we are on the wrong track, before the freight train arrives..

Comment: And that means I also have to import the picture, right? If I delete the picture I imported, it doesn't show up again. And what's function of "super.paintComponent(g)"?

Comment: Ah! I understand!. Is it because I imported the picture and then it exists in the E:/eclipse/EL file system, and if I delete it, the picture in the file is also deleted? So the background won't show up.